# How can i return warning message from .NET CORE API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Angular on client-side. I am using .NET CORE WEB API on server-side and i'm using SQL Server for database. My WEB API has layers. Business Logic Layer does database dml operations for me and i was able to do get and post http client operations. But i have to check data in Business Logic Layer if data is wrong formatted i want to show an error on client like "This phone number is wrong formatted. Please enter correct format". I did DML (INSERT,SELECT) operations correctly. I need help for returning error message and i want to show this error message to users.

This is .NET Core Web API PersonController.cs

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class PersonController : ControllerBase
    {
        FihristBLL bll = new FihristBLL();

        // GET: api/Person
        [HttpGet]
        public List<Person> Get()
        {
            return bll.GetNumbers();
        }


        // POST: api/Person
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] Person person)
        {
            bll.AddNumber(person);
        }
    }
}
```

This is Business Logic Layer doing database operations

```
    public class FihristBLL
    {
        public void AddNumber(Person person)
        {


                if (person.PhoneNumber.Substring(0, 1) != "5" || 0 % Convert.ToInt64(person.PhoneNumber) != 0)
                {
                // WRONG FORMAT


                }

                else
                {
                    // CORRECT FORMAT      
                    FihristDAL db = new FihristDAL();
                    SqlConnection conn = db.OpenConnection();
                    string command = "INSERT INTO Persons (PhoneNumber,FirstName,LastName) VALUES (@phoneNumber,@firstName,@lastName)";
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = db.CreateConnection(command);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneNumber", person.PhoneNumber);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", person.FirstName);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", person.LastName);
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();


                }     
        }
    }
}
```

Operations perfectly work fine. But i need to return error messages like "You just entered wrong formatted phone number." and display this message on Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick response would be to throw an `ArgumentException` with the description of the validation error, catch it at controller level and map it into an error response with the exception´s message as content:

```
var validPhoneNumber = //your validation logic stuff
if (!validPhoneNumber ){
   throw new ArgumentException("Invalid phone number");
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Person person)
{
    try{
      bll.AddNumber(person);
    }catch(ArgumentException argumentEx){
       return BadRequest(new {Message = argumentEx.Message});
    }
    // A better approach would be to return the created resource at this point
    return this.NoContent();
}
```

On the angular side, the error payload should be available in an instance of `HttpResponseError`.

If you want to implement a cleaner/better approach, I would recommend you to start by reading [the msc docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2) about the topic. You might then opt in to use a validation library other than the built-in one, eg. `FluentValidation`. After that, you might as well go with more complex stuff as described in [this blog entry](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/handling-errors-in-asp.net-core-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to encapsulate validation logic in an object, serialize that object and send it to angular, then in angular check if everything is ok move onward, otherwise show some error messages.

Comment: I would not do that. As the JavaScript that will be performing the validation logic is run in the users browser and can be edited by the user. So, with enough technical know how, the user could delete/ comment out the validation code and circumvent it

Comment: @MindSwipe The validation would be performed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the model and return it.

```
public class Response<T>
{
        public Response(bool defalut = false)
        {
            IsSuccess = defalut;
            Message = "";
        }

        public Response(string message)
        {
            IsSuccess = false;
            Message = message;
        }

        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When the format is wrong you can throw an exception and simply return a [HttpResponseMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=netframework-4.8) like so:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] Person person)
{
    try 
    {
        bll.AddNumber(person);
    }
    // Replace with own exception
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            ReasonPhrase = "Phone number is not correctly formatted"
        };
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: Okay i did that but how can i use HttpResponseMessage in Angular?

Comment: [This](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details) part of the angular documentation is about error handling with http clients and [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) part is about making a post request. As HTTP status code 400 Bad Request is a error code it should be caught in `catchError`